# Mysql bin.log file rotation

Tags: mysql, logrotate

I am trying to change the binary log rotation from days to hours. By default there is an option only for days in mysql config file: `expire_logs_days`.

Is there any way, where i could change binary log rotation from days to hours or even minutes?

I am running mysql version 5.7.23 on ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: During db replication, we need to play with binary log file. There is option in my.cnf file where we can rotate the logs of this file. This rotation is day base rotation. I need to set this value in hours.

Comment: The option is *expire_logs_days* and the default value is 10 days and the minimum value we can set is 1 day. My concern is to minimize it less than one day i.e in hours.

Comment: I am running mysql version 5.7.23 on ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: Oh. Bad luck. :-( Since MySQL 8.0.1 there is a new setting [`binlog_expire_logs_seconds`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/replication-options-binary-log.html#sysvar_binlog_expire_logs_seconds) to allow for _seconds_ and [`expire_logs_days`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/replication-options-binary-log.html#sysvar_expire_logs_days) became deprecated. I'm afraid I cannot help you then.

Comment: You are welcome. _Maybe_ someone at https://dba.stackexchange.com/ or https://stackoverflow.com/ can help.

Comment: @Rehan let's be sure you are trying to solve the correct problem.  The setting for `expire_logs_days` does not *rotate* logs.  It *deletes* them.  Are you looking for [`max_binlog_size`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replication-options-binary-log.html#sysvar_max_binlog_size)? This is what controls log rotation -- size, not age.